# ASP.NET list of textboxes not aligning properly

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I am displaying a list of textboxes on top of an image on an ASP .NET Master/Content webpage. The image is the width of the page and has 6 even spaced white blocks. What I am trying to do is put a number in each image box white space using the CSS and HTML below. What is happening is all of the textboxes are being displayed in the same image box which is the first. In the first, the textboxes are only about 2px apart from each other and not spreading across the image 20px apart as defined it the left CSS tag. Why is my style is not correct?

```
Master:
```

// These style sheet classes match each textbox below

```
        <style>
        .floating_label1 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 115px;**
          //  border: hidden;
        }
        .floating_label2 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 130px;**
          //  border: hidden;
        }
        .floating_label3 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 150px;**
        //    border: hidden;
        }
        .floating_label4 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 170px;**
         //   border: hidden;
        }
        .floating_label5 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 190px;**
        //    border: hidden;
        }
        .floating_label6 {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 65px;
            **left: 210px;**
            border: hidden;
        }
}
    </style>
```

Content:

```
  <div style="position:relative;">
           <img src="Images/PAXSummary.jpg" />
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="1" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label1" /> 
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="2" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label2" />             
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="3" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label3" />             
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="4" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label4" />             
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text="5" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label5" />             
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text="6" style="height:25px; width:25px; vertical-align:central; text-align:center" CssClass="floating_label6" />             
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have to take into account the width of each box element, because everything about "left" is calculating from left edges. The left edge of the first box is at 130 px out, then that box continues on for 25 more pixels, ending at pixel 155. The left edge of box 2 is set to 150px which would touch the right side of box 1. If you want 20 px between each one, your values of "left" should differ by 25 + 20 rather than 20. So 130, then 175, then 220, etc.